# How do I copy reports between repositories in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have two repositories (JasperServers), one on my local machine for development and then the "production" one.

I have all of the reports on my development copy of JasperServer and everything is working well. Now, I want to copy these reports to the production copy of JasperServer. When I select copy and try to paste into the other repo, paste is grayed out.

How do I copy reports between two Jasper Server instances with iReport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iReport is the wrong tool to meet that requirement.

Use js-export and js-import to promote reports from development to production.